# Can you put a tag on a teams site webpage?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

Can you put a tag on a Microsoft Teams site webpage so when you search you get results from all the sites that have that "tag"? We have a hub site that all these sites roll up to, we would like to put "tags" on each site classifying them as a marketing site, communications, product site, etc. and then have a list on the hub site that shows the sites that contain a specific "tag".

I know you can do something like this in Confluence, just not sure if you can in SharePoint or Teams sites.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, albeit that it's a bunch of work. There are a few possible ways:

1. You can use the Content Type Hub (some intro reading [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02)), but it's a bunch of work as you need to configure the tag, push it to all sites using the hub, then set [Column Defaults](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/10/column-default-value-settings-in-sharepoint.html) across all locations (e.g. using PowerShell). Once that's done, you need to modify your [search schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema) to include that tag when indexing, re-index all the content, and finally [modify the search results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/customize-results-layout) to show the tag.
2. As an alternative, you can do this just in the [search display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/customize-results-layout) by searching for the path of the site the content comes from. This is probably the quickest and easiest.